# Nginx redirect with/without php extension

Tags: php, redirect, nginx

I am building an NGINX virtual host that should:

- redirect pages ending with .php to the version without extension (301 redirect)
- properly handle URLs not ending with .php by passing them to FASTCGI for php execution

My issue is that this will in effect create an infinite redirect loop. What am I missing here?

```
server {
  server_name ~^my\.domain\.com$;

  listen 80;
  root /path/to/root;

  error_page 404 /404.php;

  location ~ \.php$ {
    rewrite ^(.*)\.php$ $1 permanent;
    break;
  }

  location / {
    index index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ @extensionless-php;
  }

  location @extensionless-php {
      rewrite ^(.*)$ $1.php last;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

        # rest of fastcgi configuration...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For a start, you cannot have two `location ~ \.php$` blocks. The solution is to process the `fastcgi_pass` within the named location itself and avoid the internal rewrite to `.php`. Something like this:

```
location / {
    try_files     $uri @php;
}
location @php {
    try_files     $uri.php $uri/index.php =404;

    include       fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_pass  ...;
}
location ~* ^(.*)\.php$ { 
    return 301 $1; 
}
```

Notice that the `index` directive and the `$uri/` elements are no longer required.